# Factory pattern clone protected member of base class

Tags: c++, factory

This is a design question.

I need to create an object of **Derived** class based on a **Base** class object. But the protected members of **Base** are obviously not accessible inside **Derived** through a **Base** class pointer...

Is there a nice way to solve this mess without having to declare the derived class as a friend of the base class?

```
class ProtectedImpl;

class Base
{
    //friend class Derived; //this solves the problem, but...
    public:
    static Base* create()
    {
        Base* base = new Base;
        // init impl here...
        return base;
    }

    protected:
    ProtectedImpl* impl;
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
    static Derived* create()
    {
        Derived * derived = new Derived;
        // init impl here...
        return derived;
    }

    static Derived* clone(Derived* d)
    {
        Derived* derived = new Derived;
        ProtectedImpl* impl = d->impl; // OK!
        //derived->impl = ... // clone implementation here
        return derived;
    }

    /* This doesn't work 
    static Derived* clone(Base* b)
    {
        Derived* derived = new Derived;
        ProtectedImpl* impl = b->impl; // impl can't be accessed with a Base pointer
        //derived->impl = ... // clone implementation here
        return derived;
    }
    */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you introduce a setter in the base class like:

```
class Base {
    ....
protected:
    virtual void setImpl(ProtectedImpl *pImpl) {
         // check validity of pImpl here
         impl = pImpl;
    }
}
```

Then you could use this in your Derived class, and also override the default implementation if necessary.
However, your static create() function already creates an implementation, so if you want to call it, you'll need to deal with that too, possibly with a version of this setter that replaces the existing implementation with another, or by mofying create() so it accepts a pointer to an implementation with default = NULL, and use that parameter if it is not NULL.